# Using past data with present data of ArrayList inside Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

Continuous data from three sensors (*x,y, and z*) are stored in a Hashmap (sensor names as *Key* and data in ArrayList as *value*). For data from every sensor, I need to apply a low pass filter. I'm trying to do it in the following way:

```
    ArrayList<Float> TempArray = new ArrayList();
    Map<String,ArrayList<Float>> FilteredDataOfSensors = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Float>>();
    float filteredData;
    for(Map.Entry<String , ArrayList<Float>>Sensors:ContinuousDataFromSensors.entrySet())
    {
        TempArray = AccessPointId.getValue();
        String SensorName = Sensors.getKey();
        ArrayList<Float> arrayOfFilteredData = FilteredDataOfSensors.get(SensorName);
        if(arrayOfFilteredData == null)
        {
            arrayOfFilteredData = new ArrayList<Float>();
            FilteredDataOfSensors.put(SensorName,arrayOfFilteredData);
        }
        if(arrayOfFilteredData.size() == 0 && TempArray.size() == 1) {filteredData = TempArray.get(0); Log.d("Test", "Inside If");}
        else if(arrayOfFilteredData.size() == 0 && TempArray.size() > 1) {filteredData = TempArray.get(TempArray.size()-1);Log.d("Test", "Inside else If");}
      else {  FilteredData = (float) (0.5 * TempArray.get(TempArray.size()-1) + 0.5 * arrayOfFilteredData.get(arrayOfFilteredData.size()-1)); Log.d("Test", "Inside else");}
        arrayOfFilteredData.add( FilteredData);     
    }
```

While running the above code snippet, the loop never goes inside the **else** condition.

In my case, when the app starts, it may not get data from all the sensors at the beginning. The above code snippet starts when there is at least one data from each sensor. So, when the code starts, there may be many data from a sensor and only one data from another sensor. I need to filter the sensor data using the past data and current data.

The hashmap `ContinuousDataFromSensors` contains the raw data (**Key**: sensor name, **Value**: continuous sensor data in **ArrayList**)

Is my approach correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `FilteredDataOfSensors` is created before the loop runs might be your issue.  Perhaps it needs to be promoted to a class member and persisted and reused for multiple runs of the loop.

Because the `else` code you ask about only runs when a Sensor.getKey() already exists in `FilteredDataOfSensors`.  But `FilteredDataOfSensors` was just created so it is always empty when the loop begins.

Perhaps if `ContinuousDataFromSensors` which the code loops on had multiple entries for a given Sensor.getKey().  But that seems unlikely, since most maps use unique keys.  And also since multiple data points for a sensor do not go in multiple map entries, they are all in the ArrayList of one map entry)

Thanks for putting a code snippet with your question btw.  Putting the complete method or class makes it even easier to help.  Good luck!

Comment: I created 'FilteredDataOfSensors' as a class member and it worked. Thanks.